# Given any model of ZFC, $M$, is $\omega^M$ really a model of PA? Is any arbitrarily model of PA $\omega^M$ for some $M$?

Tags: logic, set-theory, natural-numbers

If $M$ is any model of ZFC then by Infinity it has a set $\omega^M$. Also $\text{ZFC} \vdash (\omega \models \text{PA})$, so $M \models (\omega \models \text{PA})$. However, what can we say externally about $\omega^M$? Does it satisfy PA? Basically, what can we say externally about the natural numbers of an arbitrary model of ZFC?

Also, given a model of ZFC, can we get another model of ZFC with (externally) natural numbers isomorphic to any chosen nonstandard model of PA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, $\omega^M$ satisfies PA.  More generally, suppose $X$ is any first-order structure internal to $M$.  Then a simple induction on formulas shows that for any first-order formula $\varphi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and any $a_1,\dots,a_n\in X$, $M\models(X\models\varphi(a_1,\dots,a_n))$ iff $X\models\varphi(a_1,\dots,a_n)$.  (To be clear, when I say $X\models\varphi(a_1,\dots,a_n)$, I really mean $X'\models\varphi(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ where $X'=\{a\in M:M\models a\in X\}$ equipped with the first-order structure defined using the internal first-order structure of $X'$.)

However, $\omega^M$ cannot be an arbitrary nonstandard model of PA.  For instance, since ZFC proves the consistency of PA, $M\models(\omega\models Con(PA))$ and thus $\omega^M$ must satisfy $Con(PA)$.

(There is an important subtlety here, which is that the argument of the first paragraph only applies when $\varphi$ is an *actual* first-order formula, i.e. an external one in the real universe, rather than a first-order formula internal to $M$.  If $\omega^M$ is nonstandard, then $M$ will have "first-order formulas" whose length is nonstandard and therefore are not actually formulas from the external perspective.  This means, for instance, that if $X$ is a structure internal to $M$ which is *externally* a model of PA, then $M$ may not think $X$ is a model of PA, since $M$ has nonstandard axioms of PA which $X$ may not satisfy.  See [this neat paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.0670) for some dramatic ways that things like this can occur.)

Comment: Hmm, I must be confused, its a while back I did set theory. Kunen spends several pages in his book proving that "$\models$" is absolute for transitive models of ZF-P (I believe). I don't know how your simple induction goes, because I have a hard time trying to see how $M$ interprets $\models$, since it is such a complex formula that is hidden there. I must be missing something.

Comment: OK, maybe I see what you can do, please tell me if it's correct. You can prove by meta induction on the formulas that $M \models (X \models \varphi(a_1, \dots, a_n))$ iff $M \models \varphi(a_1, \dots, a_n)^X$ (the relativization of $\varphi(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ to $X$). For example the induction step for $\forall$: ZFC proves that $X \models \forall x \varphi(x)$ iff for all $x \in X$ we have $X \models \varphi(x)$ iff (by induction hypothesis) for all $x \in X$ we have $\varphi(x)^X$ iff (by definition) $(\forall x \varphi(x))^X$. Also it is easily seen then that (cont.)

Comment: $M \models \varphi(a_1, \dots, a_n)^X$ iff $X \models \varphi(a_1, \dots, a_n)$. Something like this... but then what is the point of Kunen's long proof?

Comment: You can argue like that, but there's not any need to talk about relativization at all: almost the exact same steps just show directly that $M \models (X \models \varphi(a_1, \dots, a_n))$ iff $X \models \varphi(a_1, \dots, a_n)$.

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, what's the point of Kunen long proof then? It is much weaker (transitive models of ZF-P) yet way more complicated proof. Is the only point that Kunen's absoluteness results works for nonstandard formulas as well? But

Comment: I don't know what Kunen's proof is.  It's possible he's just writing out the argument in fuller detail.  Or maybe he is building up some different machinery along the way that is useful for other purposes.

Comment: That fair enough. But I'm still not very convinced :). For example, how do we even know that if $M$ thinks $X$ is a structure, then $X$ actually is. Sorry, if this is a stupid question but I find it still quite confusing. I will reward a 50 point bounty if you can add the simple induction proof and explain it a bit. Also, what we we need to assume on $M$? Is ZF-P enough?

Answer (score 4):

To your first question, the answer is yes. Since "the real axioms of $\sf PA$" are always included in "the internal version of $\sf PA$" (because they are coded by standard integers, which are always present), the answer is trivial: any relation satisfying *all* the axioms of $\sf PA$ must also satisfy all the external axioms of $\sf PA$.

To your second questions, the answer is obviously not: take any model of $\sf PA+\lnot\operatorname{Con}(PA)$, for example. This cannot be the $\omega$ of any model of $\sf ZF$, since $\sf ZF\vdash\operatorname{Con}(PA)$.

Comment: Hey Asaf, do you know why Kunen (in his Set Theory book) has quite a bit of machinery to prove that $\models$ is absolute for transitive models of ZF-P, while Eric's proof above seems much easier and is completely general for every model?

Comment: I understand this answer, but only in conjunction with the result "$M\models(X\models\varphi(a_1,\dots,a_n))$ iff $X\models\varphi(a_1,\dots,a_n)$" that Eric mentions above.

Comment: I never really read Kunen. I started reading the old book when I was starting out, but I didn't really click with it and I switched to Jech. Kunen is quite a formal writer, and even when he tries to impart intuition, he also tries to be very very accurate (some people like that, I don't). So I can't quite help you with that. As Eric said, maybe he has some broader use of the machinery in mind, or maybe he just wants to be 100% accurate and without any room for ambiguity.

Comment: Really? This is my second year of master's and I still find Jech quite formidable. Very readable and complete, but not much explicit intuition. E.g. Kunen also explains sometimes why some approach doesn't work. The only intuition in Jech is the order of the theorems :')

Comment: I did hear that the new version is much better. But at that point I already knew a lot of it, and didn't feel the need to chase down the book.

Comment: You did an amazing amount of set theory in just a master... seeing the time stamps of your old answers. I thought 3-4 courses was already a lot haha!

Comment: Thanks. I had free time (the courses at BGU were not as heavy as advertised, but they kind of do it on purpose so you have time for research), and I had nobody to ask back then (only my advisor, but he was mostly out of office). That being said, I learned a lot, but not very deep. It took me until the end of my PhD and even later to fully internalise most of the concepts that I supposedly asked about. (Also helped: taking two year-long courses with Menachem Magidor about very advanced topics.)